# Bash: history-search-backwards broken after ssh

Tags: bash, readline

I regularly ssh from my laptop (mac) to my desktop (linux), and sometimes, afterwards, the history-search-backwards ends up broken and just acts like previous-history. (I have not tracked whether it only and always happens after broken sessions, vs. cleanly disconnected ones.)

My first suspicion was that somehow my readline settings were getting reset. But both before and after the issue appears, my relevant readline settings are the same:

```
$ bind -p | grep history | egrep -v "^# "
"\e<": beginning-of-history
"\e\C-i": dynamic-complete-history
"\e>": end-of-history
"\C-s": forward-search-history
"\e^": history-expand-line
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\C-n": next-history
"\eOB": next-history
"\en": non-incremental-forward-search-history
"\ep": non-incremental-reverse-search-history
"\C-p": previous-history
"\eOA": previous-history
"\C-r": reverse-search-history
```

Oddly, printing the up arrow in vi shows it as `^[OA` not as `\e[A` as I would have suspected. But either way, it also doesn't change between when my binding is what I want, and when it no longer is.

What is causing this? How do I reset my key bindings? How do I avoid the problem in the future?

Comment: I don't know Mac but in my Kubuntu I would try the `reset` command (which is, I believe, a special case of `tset`).

Comment: Thanks, @kamil-maciorowski. That worked. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: My comment was not posted as an answer for a reason: it answers just one of your *three* questions. If you think it's enough, you should get rid of the other questions first (by [edit]ing). However this would make the question duplicate [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1336947/432690) (symptoms differ but the fix is the same); so if you edit, I will vote to close the question as duplicate. I cannot answer all the questions and I'm refusing to write a *partial* answer with just `reset`; but if anyone (including you) does then I will neither interfere nor claim credit.

Comment: This question is better asked, thus Google found it instead of the linked question in the comment. `reset` is an answer, better than anything else I have found.