# Linux cat command to read the content of binary or pdf file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, pdf

So I tried to read the content of a file with cat command. But the output was gibberish as the file was a binary file, and that I can understand. But the output was very different from what I see on other files. See the
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQgJA.png).
 What you don't see is my command `cat filename.extension`
then the gibberish output came out, it seems that the file ended but continued again(I did nothing other than enter the first command).

So what is happening? (Please don't tell me I should use `strings` command)

Comment: The terminal is interpreting the binary output as best it can. If it finds valid control sequences in the binary file then anything can happen, for example the cursor can move to another part of the screen ...

Comment: Why are you `cat`ing binary files?

Comment: @DavidPostill, you probably did not see the last line of my question.

Comment: DavidPostill comment is entirely appropriate to your question as asked. It does not mention "string"

Answer (score 3):

> the file ended but continued again

Some bytes in the gibberish data were interpreted as control sequences. See [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code):

> Certain sequences of bytes, most starting with Esc and `[`, are embedded into the text, which the terminal looks for and interprets as commands, not as character codes.

In effect at some point your cursor moved up without clearing the screen, few more lines were printed and the command prompt appeared over the *old* output.

Some aftermath may be semi-permanent. Please read [*Weird characters appearing in the console*](https://superuser.com/q/1336947/432690) and my answer there.

Comment: Thanks man. I'll see if the links answer my question.