# See htop tree evolve in slow-motion

Tags: terminal, unix, process, htop

Using `htop` and its tree view (trigger by `t` or `F5`) one can see processes by parenthood, and layout the relations between them as a tree.

**Is there a way to see how the process tree evolves in slow motion?** That is, record the history somehow and play it back at a custom speed, a bit like a video player that allows stepping through frame by frame? Right now, it sometimes flashes by too fast to keep track of.

Alternative tools to `htop` are welcome too.

Comment: I know [`atop`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop) can be configured to log system events and play them back, I don't know if it can be set up to achieve what you want though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Limited generic way to replay in slow motion

You can use `script` to record `htop`, like:

```
script -O typescript -T typescript.timing -c 'htop -t'
```

`script` will exit just after `htop` exits. Alternatively:

```
script -O typescript -T typescript.timing
```

puts you in a shell where you can run `htop -t` and/or whatever. In this method it's important to `exit` the shell; only then `script` exits.

After `script` exits, you can replay in slow motion:

```
scriptreplay typescript.timing typescript 0.1
```

Limitations:

- `script` records what happens in a terminal session. In your case it does not really record the process tree. It records what `htop` prints and it so happens it prints the tree. But if `htop` does not show you some process (because it's transient or you're just scrolling through the wrong part of the tree) then `scriptreplay` won't show the process either. Consider `htop -t -d 1` to make transient processes more likely to be seen. Anyway **`script`+`htop` is by no means a reliable way to audit processes in your OS.** I mean you can and will miss out on some processes.
- What happens in a terminal session depends on the size of the terminal. Playing it back in a terminal of a different size (especially if smaller in any direction) may cause misalignments, artifacts and such. Resizing the terminal during playback may cause additional artifacts.
- If you interrupt `scriptreplay` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> then you may need to [run `reset` or in another way bring your terminal to a sane state](https://superuser.com/a/1336953/432690).
- AFAIK `scriptreplay` is not interactive, one cannot even pause it. I have found [`scriptreplay_ng`](https://github.com/scoopex/scriptreplay_ng), it seems somewhat better in this aspect; but I haven't tested.