# Terminal settings get corrupted

Tags: linux, terminator

I work quite heavily in console, namely in terminator.
At some point my terminal settings get "corrupted":

- The screen size becomes much smaller than the terminator "working pane" size
- Previous line in the output is removed by using history (up arrow)

While searching for the culprit process, that does it can be complicated, is there a way to quickly reset the settings (such that the terminal screen again fits into terminator size and browsing the history does not eat up output)? Without restarting terminator.

My environment:
Ubuntu 20.04
Terminator 1.91-4ubuntu1

Comment: (1) *Maybe* [this](https://superuser.com/a/1336953/432690) will help; does it? (2) Do you use some fancy `$PS1`? Or `$PROMPT_COMMAND` in Bash? Or something similar in whatever shell you use?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll try out "reset" next time when it happens.
And yes, I "load" my PS1 with git branch name like this. Maybe some wrong stuff is echo'ed by that function, that echo'es the branch name to PS1 value sometimes.